# Traveling - can I connect this adapter?

Tags: power, voltage, adapter

I'm new here - computers are my thing, but I could use some electrics help. I have travelled to a small island where I will be for several months.

I managed to bring everything except one power adapter.

I do have something "similar" and want to ask if this will work before blowing myself up.

The power requirement on the device is 12V 1.5A positive center.

I have an adapter that works on local current. It's output is 12V 1A. (12VA). Any chance this will work?

And, just in case, which way is the diagram for positive center?

Many thanks

Comment: It has the plus pointing to the center.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. sorry for the dupe. I'll look first next time.

Comment: No worries. Sometimes *just* the right query to find the duplicate can be tricky to get right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any adapter with the same rated voltage and the ***same or Greater amperage***.  If you use an adapter with a lower rated amperage, it will get hot when your device demands greater than what it is rated for and it could burn out or even start a fire.

Don't use it!

Comment: Thanks to all. I appreciate the fast responses, and clarity in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Take care!
Your PC's rating is 1.5Amps this means it can at some point withdraw 1.5amps.
While your adapter can supply only up to 1Amps. 
You might burn up the adapter at some point. I recommend you getting > 1.5Amps power supply.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not a PC, seeing as how most would need at least 10A if not more.

Comment: I assumed that because he said and I quote "computers are my thing", and he's leaving to an island. 
But, I guess you're right!

Comment: I should have said - this is for an internet telephone adapter :)